# C++ send data serial port Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I'm writing a C++ application (for Windows 7) and I need to send some data through the serial port for an Arduino. I found some code snippets googling, but most of the code it's outdated.
Which libraries should I use and where can I found a detailed explanation with examples?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Show your workaround/code first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question, as it is currently posed, will likely be closed as off topic. I recommend reading [ask] for tips on how to improve the question and bring it on topic.

Comment: @code0 I searched on the official board/forum first, but most of the code is for Linux OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libserial: https://github.com/crayzeewulf/libserial/

It is an excellent library for serial port communications with C++.
You'll find some easy to use examples in the examples folder on the git repo.

However, if the task gets too complicated I would recommend using Arduino's libraries ie. SoftwareSerial to make your task easier.